# using stored procedure in hibernate 3

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures

Hello I am using hibernate + spring since 5 months but never used stored procedure in hibernate so please can anybody tell me how to call stored procedure from DB(MySQL)....

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate defines stored procedure calls as a named query. The docs explain [how to set this up](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/querysql.html#sp_query) in the Hibernate config.

From Spring, you can call a named query using the various `HibernateTemplate.findByNamedQuery(...)` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Spring has an [StoredProcedure](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/object/StoredProcedure.html) class that you can extend to call stored procedures.

```
class MyStoredProcedure extends StoredProcedure {
     public MyStoredProcedure(DataSource ds) {
          this.setDataSource(ds);
          this.setSql("store_procedure_name");
          this.declareParameter(new SqlParameter("name", Types.VARCHAR);
          this.compile();
     }

     public void callProcedure() {
          Map<string, String> inParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
          inParams.put("name", "taher");
          try {
               execute(inParams);
          } catch (DataAccessException dae) {
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: That's not using Hibernate, though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using Spring with Hibernate I would suggest using Spring classes. You can extend the StoredProcedure class mentioned above, there are other alternatives as well. If you have a basic stored procedure I would say the easiest way to call it would be to use Spring's [SimpleJdbcCall](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/) class. The [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-simple-jdbc-call-1) covers this class quite nicely with code snippets.